# What is the definition of a minorant/majorant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

What is the definition of a minorant?

For context, a statistics paper I am reading describes a finite sequence of positive, strictly decreasing, strictly convex sequence $\{\Gamma_n \} = \Gamma_1, \Gamma_2, \ldots \Gamma_n$.  Then an estimator of this sequence (still positive but no longer strictly decreasing or convex) is $\{\hat{\Gamma}_n \} = \hat{\Gamma}_1, \hat{\Gamma}_2, \ldots \hat{\Gamma}_n$.  Then what is the minorant of $k \mapsto \hat{\Gamma}_k$?

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Majorant_and_minorant

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, so the majorant is the least upper bound of a sequence and the minorant is the greatest lower bound?

Comment: seems that way from my reading ( see the comment listed)